# JSlint: redefinition of i inside of function scope

Tags: javascript, jslint

When running the following Javascript code through JSLint:

```
    (function () {
        var i = 'a';

        console.log(i);

        function foo () {
            var i = 'b';
            console.log(i);
        }

        foo();

        console.log(i);

        foo();
    }());
```

I get the following errors in JSLint:

```
    #1 Redefinition of 'i' from line 4.
       var i = 'b'; // Line 7, Pos 13
    #2 Unused 'i'.
       var i = 'a'; // Line 4, Pos 9
    #3 Unused 'foo'.
        function foo () { // Line 6, Pos 14
```

My questions:

1. Why does it say foo() is unused when I am clearly calling it?
2. Why does it say the function-scoped `var i = 'b'` is a redefinition of the one above it
3. Why does it say that the first `var i = 'a'` definition goes unused?

Comment: Put the function declaration first, then `var`, this way the declarations are in correct order, and JSLint won't report any errors.

Comment: @Teemu: Perhaps a better example would be a closure being used as a callback. If you define the `var i` inside that closure, JSLint reports the same error

Comment: It's all about hoisting. Function and variable declarations are hoisted to the top of their scope, functions should be first, then variables. If they are not in correct order, JSLint reports an error, and obviously can't handle the rest of the code correctly, at least from human aspect "Unused variables" feels illogical.

Comment: Okay, perhaps a better question - why am I getting "Redefinition of 'i'" here: http://pastie.org/9113006

Comment: Hard to say, maybe you've to ask mr Crockford ; ).

Comment: The pastie gets the same complaint because the anonymous function declared in `_([1, 2, 3]).each(function () {` redefines `i` on the next line, just like Filipe's sample code, above. It's an anonymous function, but it's still a new function with a new closure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, if you run the code at jslint.com, you only get the redefinition error, which is valid.  So I'm not sure why you're seeing errors 1 & 3.  How are you linting?  Is it within another app?  What date of jslint.js are you using?  etc etc

```
/*jslint sloppy:true, white:true, browser:true, devel:true */
(function () {
    var i = 'a';

    console.log(i);

    function foo () {
        var i = 'b';
        console.log(i);
    }

    foo();

    console.log(i);

    foo();
}());
```

That gives me only...

```
Redefinition of 'i' from line 3.
            var i = 'b';
```

Fair enough.  Same deal from the pastie in your question's comments.  As Jeremy says, the code won't break.  It's just confusing.  Why *not* use `j` (or, of course, a descriptive var name in live code) in `foo` or the anonymous function used in the pastie's `each`?

When you use JSLint, it's important to keep in mind that [Crockford believes](http://www.jslint.com/lint.html), "It is difficult to write correct programs while using idioms that are hard to distinguish from obvious errors."  Covering your outer `i` with `foo`'s inner `i` is confusing.

Imagine if `foo` read...

```
    function foo () {
        console.log("Maybe I think I'm getting old 'i' here: " + i);

        var i = 'b';
        console.log(i);
    }
```

JSLint (strangely, if you ask me) doesn't require that the `var` statement be the first line in each scope, only that it occurs before you reference the variables.

So if you run your test code with that new `foo`, you'll get undefined for `foo`'s `i` before you hit the declaration statement b/c of variable hoisting.  Bizarre, right?  (Or expected, depending on your JS experience!)

```
a
Maybe I think I'm getting old 'i' here: undefined
b
a
Maybe I think I'm getting old 'i' here: undefined
b
```

You could argue that JSLint got that one wrong -- that it should have not only complained about the `Redefinition`, but should have also complained that `'i' was used before it was defined.` within `foo`'s scope.  I won't argue that.  ;^)

I will say, however, that the redefinition is an idiom that's hard to distinguish from an obvious error.  Best practice?  Don't reuse variable names for different values in overlapping scopes.

Comment: Thanks, great explanation of the reasoning behind it.

Answer (score 2):

You are getting the redefinition of `i` because it exists in both scopes.

This isn't really a problem, per se, however it is one thing that Crockford believes can cause confusing, so his tool catches it.